# keep web crawlers out of your site

Tags: web-crawler

Is there any way in web development to ensure that web crawlers cannot crawl your website?

Comment: Why? Is this for while you're developing, but in a "live" area? Or do you want this even for a live site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure? No.

You can ask politely with [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html) (but they can be ignored), you can stick up barriers with [CAPTCHA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) (but they can be defeated and impose a barrier to ordinary users), and you can monitor the behaviour of each visitor looking for bot patterns (but bots can proxy cycle and rate limit).

Answer (score 1):

You could place a [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/) file with the following contents at the root of your site which will prevent the civilized robots from indexing it:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Notice that this won't prevent the uncivilized robots from indexing it. The only way to prevent them is using techniques such as Captcha.

Of course it is preferred to use a dedicated development machine which is not accessible from the internet while your site is under construction.

Answer (score 1):

You could also deny access based on the crawlers [user agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent), of course this assumes that the crawler uses a user agent different from a regular browser.

Comment: "Bad" crawlers can always fake the user agent, so it is also just one of methods which can help, but mot prohibit them

Answer (score 0):

Use robots.txt to direct or allow/disallow robots from indexing your website.

Comment: Note that `robots.txt` can be ignored by crawlers, as David and Darin both mentioned.